# How to merge Django queryset result, collecting values from matching keys?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

My Views.py

```
context['user'] = User.objects.filter(code='01').values('name', 'phone')
print(context['user'])
```

The current results are as follows:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'John', 'cellphone': '1234567890'}, {'name': 'Doe', 'cellphone': '1234512345'}]>
```

How can I get a result like this from templates?

```
{% for u in user %}
 <span>name :</span> <span> {{ u.name }} / </span>
 <span>cellphone :</span> <span> {{ u.cellphone }}</span>
{% endfor %}

# want result
 name : John, Doe / cellphone : 1234567890, 1234512345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop twice.

```
<span>name :</span>
{% for u in user %}
{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ u.name }}
{% endfor %}
<span> / cellphone :</span>
{% for u in user %}
{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ u.cellphone }}
{% endfor %}
```